# Is it possible to use Java as a scripting language in unity?

Tags: unity, java, 2d, scripting, unityscript

I wonder if its possible to use Java as a scripting language in unity to create a basic 2d game?

Comment: It shouldn't...

Comment: If you want to use java why don't you use jMonkey instead of unity. jMonkey is (on a high level) similar to unity but java

Answer (score 0):

No. As far as i know, Unity is only made to use JavaScript and C#.

Comment: Boo was dropped in unity 5

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - No.
Unity only supports: UnityScript (JavaScript for Unity) and C#.
[Boo support dropped in Unity 5.](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/03/documentation-unity-scripting-languages-and-you/)

But C# is very similar to Java, and I for myself started only with Java knowledge and it was no problem for me to learn C#.

Comment: I don't think Boo is supported in unity 5

Comment: @Bálint Although you can't create new Boo scripts from the editor anymore, the Boo scripting engine still works just as before. This was necessary to allow to port games using Boo to Unity 5 and to not alienate those developers who still insist on using Boo (both of them).